# Background Service sendo morto no android

Tags: android, background-services

Criamos uma aplicação de monitoramento de GPS, a cada 30 segundos mais ou menos o aplicativo atualiza no servidor a posição do usuário. Com as mudanças recentes do Android 8 e seguintes, vimos que a questão de uso da bateria foi bastante reforçada pelo android, o que faz com que alguns aparelhos/fabricantes, matem serviços que rodam em background depois de um tempo.
E basicamente é o que está acontecendo conosco, principalmente em aparelhos Xiaomi.

A dúvida é, é possível contornar esse cenário? Recriar um serviço sempre que ele for morto pelo android?

Answer (score 0):

Estou totalmente por fora de Android atualmente, mas serviços sempre foram coisas voláteis, que não devem rodar de maneira prolongada porque sempre foram sujeitos a serem mortos pelo SO.

Nesse caso o certo então não é deixar o serviço rodando e dormente a maior parte do tempo, e sim agendar (schedule) uma tarefa (não lembro o nome do componente que faz isso no Android) para se repetir de 30 em 30 segundos que dispara um broadcast receiver que chama um serviço de curta duração que lê o GPS e transmite a posição para o servidor (com eventual bufferização local se necessário para o caso de faltar conectividade na hora).